# Xamarin.Forms: How to build an AlertDialog with an ActivityIndicator?

Tags: xamarin, dialog, xamarin.forms, loading, android-alertdialog

In my app I'm downloading images from my server. This is taking a while. In this time I want to show a window that looks like an alertDialog that have to buttons, but an activityIndicator. After the images are loaded, the navigationController push another page.
I read about using a RelativeLayout and put that "waitingAlert" above the other view. 
The question is how?
Has anybody an existing app with such an alert implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great cross-platform NuGet package for this:

https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

You can create any dialog that suits your needs. The other solution will be to use the dependency service to display a custom a alert.